# How do I view and edit Visual Basic Power Pack shapes in a Windows Form app with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, winforms, designer, visual-studio-2022, powerpacks

I've got a windows forms app created in an older version of Visual Studio (VS2019).
When I open it in VS2022, none of the Power Pack shapes are show in the design view.
I've got the Power Pack dll in references.

Opening the projects with VS2022 the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks controls disappear from the design screen even though everything is referenced correctly, the project is compiled without errors and the controls are visible in the application when it runs.

I have tried inserting Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks elements from the toolbox but it doesn’t work, everything compiles but the components are not visible in the design (only in runnig application).

I want to use the new version of Visual Studio (VS2022).

[image: Here is the reference to Power Pack:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts I managed to get the .dll to work with version 9.0.0, version 12.0.0 seems not to work.
With this, the shapes are visible and editable even in design.

Combination Working:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64 bit) - Current Version
  17.3.2
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.04084
- Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks Version 9.0.0 / Runtime Version
  2.0.50727

I hope this will Help

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by using PowerPack v3.0. Version 10 and 12 does not work for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Malavida**.com archives ***Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0*** (version 9.0.30214.0) this works fine with VS2022 (I have VS 17.5.3):

**https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/visual-basic-power-packs/**

(no goofy pre-install download transformers there; just the pristine program).

Remember they work only for .NET 4 and lower (Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)).